# Problem of installation of CVXPY on MS Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, anaconda, cvxpy

I am trying to install CVXPY on windows.

1. I had installed Anaconda.
2. I am following https://www.cvxpy.org/install/index.html  'conda' part
3. Steps I~III look fine. However, when doing `conda install pytest` and `pytest cvxpy/tests` error pops up

[image]

run in Anaconda Prompt (anaconda3)

And when I run Jupyter notebook on Anaconda, it shows
[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: Not sure if those problems are related as the tests won't do like that for me too. What happens when starting the interpreter within anaconda and importing cvxpy then? Asking, as `Steps I~III look fine` and `ModuleNotFound` error really looks strange (and often people are using different installed interpreters without knowing it: doing it in the console where install was successfull should get rid of this source of error).